# If $\sum_n\|x_n-x_{n-1}\|^2<\infty$, is $(x_n)$ Cauchy?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space and $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq E$. We can easily show that if $(\varepsilon_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq[0,\infty)$ is summable and $$d(x_n,x_{n+1})\le\varepsilon_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N,\tag1$$ then $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is Cauchy.

Now let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}\subseteq H$ and $h_n:=x_n-x_{n-1}$. Assume $(h_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is orthogonal and $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\|h_n\right\|_H^2<\infty$.

> Are we able to conclude that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is Cauchy?

We cannot apply the former result for general metric spaces, since we've only got $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\|h_n\right\|_H^{\color{red}2}<\infty$. On the other hand, this implies that $(h_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is summable. Is this enough to obtain that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is Cauchy?

Comment: By summability we have $$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} (x_N-x_1) =\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j=2}^N h_j =\sum_{n\geq 2} h_n. $$ Thus, we get that $$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} x_N =x_1 +\sum_{n\geq 2} h_n. $$ As the sequence converges, it is in particular a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: $\sum a_n^2<\infty$ does not imply $\sum a_n<\infty$: take $a_n=1/n$.

Comment: @daw I am more than aware of that. But the OP noted already that orthogonality implies summability. In fact was my first comment, which I deleted after rereading the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Let $\varepsilon>0$ and find $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{j=n_0+1}^\infty\|h_j\|^2<\varepsilon^2$. Now let $m>n\ge n_0$. We have $x_m-x_n=x_m-x_{m-1}+x_{m-1}-x_{m-2}+\dots+x_{n+1}-x_n=\sum_{j={n+1}}^{m}h_j$. Therefore
$$\|x_n-x_m\|^2=\bigg\|\sum_{j=n+1}^mh_j\bigg{\|}^2=\sum_{j=n+1}^m\|h_j\|^2\le\sum_{j=n_0+1}^\infty\|h_j\|^2<\varepsilon^2$$
so $\|x_n-x_m\|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: To the downvoter: I don't see where I am mistaken, this is why I posted my answer. Please explain what is the mistake, instead of just downvoting. I am answering questions here regularly, I'd gladly delete my post if there is a mistake. This toxic behavior only makes MSE worse.

Comment: I don't see any issue, I think the fact that the $h_j$ are orthogonal is crucial though.

Comment: Yours is correct: orthogonality is the key.

Comment: Exactly, one cannot just do a triangle inequality and expect something to come out of square-summability.

Comment: I jumped to fast to the conclusion. Have seen too much dissertations that used that 'argument'

Comment: @daw No problem. You've seen such a mistake in phd theses you mean? Wow